# Error while running circuit.draw(output='mpl')

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I have just started learning Quantum Computing using Qiskit and was trying to draw my quantum circuit using the command `circuit.draw(output='mpl')`. However, it throws an exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MissingOptionalLibraryError               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-bd220039ee1c> in <module>
----> 1 circuit.draw(output='mpl')

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/qiskit/utils/lazy_tester.py in require_now(self, feature)
    222             return
    223         raise MissingOptionalLibraryError(
--> 224             libname=self._name, name=feature, pip_install=self._install, msg=self._msg
    225         )
    226 

MissingOptionalLibraryError: "The 'pylatexenc' library is required to use 'MatplotlibDrawer'. You can install it with 'pip install pylatexenc'."

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I tried installing the `pylatexenc` library, as mentioned in the exception using the command `!pip install pylatexenc`, imported it using `from pylatexenc import *` and then tried to use the command `circuit.draw(output='mpl')` again, but it still throws the same exception.

To make sure that the library was installed properly, I re-ran the command `!pip install pylatexenc`, but then it shows:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: pylatexenc in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (2.10)
```

Here is my complete code, I am running it in Google Collab's Jupyter Notebook:

```
from qiskit import *
from pylatexenc import *

qr = QuantumRegister(2)
cr = ClassicalRegister(2)

circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)

%matplotlib inline

circuit.draw(output='mpl')
```

One more point to add:
`circuit.draw()` and `circuit.draw(initial_state = True)` seem to work properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use google collab, then:

1. Use "pip install pylatexenc",
2. Restart the runtime,
3. Execute your code again.

This should help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Ruslan. However, it turns out that installing `pylatexenc` wasn't the only thing that needed to be done. One more thing that needed to be done was to configure the jupyter notebook with my IBM account, as I have mentioned in my answer. Thanks for your answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

I think understood the mistake that I was making. So, first I ran the code on the Jupyter Notebook that I had set up on my local computer and it worked perfectly fine. However, when I tried to run the same code on the online Google Collab's Jupyter Notebook, it started throwing the exception. Now I am not sure if my solution is correct, but this is the difference and by running this command in the online environment, it works:

in addition to the existing process of installing the `pylatexenc` library, I also had to run this command:

`IBMQ.save_account('your IBMQ API key')`