# circuit.draw(output='mpl') gives error "The 'pylatexenc' library is required to use 'MatplotlibDrawer"

Tags: python, qiskit

I can't run the following command because I get an error

```
circuit.draw(output='mpl')
```

Error text:

> MissingOptionalLibraryError: "The 'pylatexenc' library is required to use 'MatplotlibDrawer'. You can install it with 'pip install pylatexenc'.

my code :

```
!pip inatall qiskit
!pip install pylatexenc
```

```
from qiskit import *
%matplotlib inline
from pylatexenc import *

qr = QuantumRegister(2)
cr = ClassicalRegister(2)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr,cr)

circuit.draw(output='mpl')
```

Comment: Your question is poorly formatted. You can enclose each portion of code with three grave accents: ``` to help people distinguish between the code and the question. To me, it seems you lack the `pylatexenc`  library. Have you tried manually installing it (e.g. with `pip install pylatexenc` in a terminal or with `!pip install pylatexenc` directly in the notebook) as the error message suggests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while running circuit.draw(output='mpl')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73646675/error-while-running-circuit-drawoutput-mpl)

Comment: I did that but still getting this error :
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73646675/error-while-running-circuit-drawoutput-mpl)

Comment: Why are you using `!` in front of your pip commands? Are you using iPython for this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happend to me about a month ago. The thing that I suggest you to do is to once uninstall your Qiskit with

```
pip uninstall qiskit
```

in your kernel. I mostly use the Pyhton version 10.11 which is more compatible for to use Qiskit and Qutip together. Maybe it is a personal experience, but when I work with Python 12, I encounter weird errors.

Comment: "Uninstall X" in answer to how to do something in X is tantamount to a troll answer.